# A Meeting on the Beach

Tags: wordplay, lateral-thinking

When I lived in Brevard County, FL, I was less than a half hour's drive away from the ocean. I arranged with someone I had talked to online to meet at the beach. I knew that she either went to my college, or that she attended a college online, but I couldn't remember which. I arrived, and after an awkward few seconds, we were able to identify each other. I was still in my regular clothes, and so was she, but she had a towel spread across the sand. I asked her whether she attended my college. Lying, on her back, she said, "Yes."
Further, she stated, "I have been going to your college for about a year now." The puzzle is this: does she go to my college or doesn't she? (Yes, I really provided enough information!)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that she

> Does not attend the college

Because

> The phrase 'Lying, on her back, she said' has a comma after lying. She is lying.

Comment: You got it! This is adapted from a "monkey trick" Raymond Smullyan was fond of. I feared that the question might be too simplistic, but I might have Asperger Syndrome, so it's hard for me to understand how other people's brains work.

Comment: @Wafflebaby this was a good one. Don't worry, nobody really knows how others' brains work.

Comment: I'm just kind of freaking out because I thought I had a pretty good guess as to the answer of a puzzle, but when I answered, people got really hostile, telling me that my answer is not an answer, when it makes sense to me and I have sources I double-checked to make sure I wasn't misremembering anything. But I also have fear of imperfection and being judged. I'm sorry to go off topic, but I feel like if I don't get this off my chest, I'll have a panic attack or something.

Comment: @Wafflebaby Then welcome on puzzling.SE, this is the friendly place you need. You'll hardly meet hostile people on this site.

Comment: @xhienne I am trying to not take it personally when people put my puzzles on hold or delete my answers, correct or otherwise. I think I'll be able to fall asleep now thanks to your kind words. I'm just used to people saying that my work is superior, so such actions on short notice make me feel like I'm not really an important thing after all, and my mom is lying about my ideas being worthy of existence, or my right to existence.

Comment: This is a Raymond Smullyan Puzzle. Most probably from the book called "What is the Name of this Book ?"...Felt nice to see it again. @Wafflebaby. Haha =D. And needless to say, Welcome on Puzzling Stack Exchange, mate. :)